# Search an DOM element by attribute name

Tags: jquery, html

How can I search (using jQuery) for a DOM element that has an attribute with a given name (not by attribute value)?

For example:

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2" myattr="myvalue">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to search for every element under `#div1` (inclusive) that has has an attribute named `myattr` (so that `#div2` element will be returned).

Comment: Have you tried the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ - definitely tried. Couldn't apply that successfully, but thanks to the answering people :)

Comment: So it is not enough to point in the direction of the docs, you also need [the actual line](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) highlighted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
$('#div1[myattr], #div1 [myattr]')
```

This will look for all `#div1` with the attribute `myattr` and **items under** `#div1` that has an attribute named `myattr`.

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery for that:

```
$('#div1 [myattr]')
```

This will find any element under `#div1` which has a `myattr` attribute (with any value).

As pointed out by a commenter, this would not include `div1`. So update the selector to:

```
$('#div1[myattr], #div1 [myattr]')
```